# ${x_n} \to x$ weakly, and $T$ is compact .Why does $\left\| {T{x_n} - Tx} \right\| \to 0$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T \in B(X,Y)$, if ${x_n} \to x$ weakly, and $T$ is compact operator.Why does $\left\| {T{x_n} - Tx} \right\| \to 0$?

Answer (score 2):

First of all note that $Tx_n \to Tx$ weakly, this is easily seen by taking any $g\in Y^*$ and observing that $f=g\circ T \in X^*$ (can you se why ? ), hence since $x_n \to x$ weakly
$$
f(x_n) \to f(x) \ \Longrightarrow g(Tx_n) \to g(Tx)
$$
Thus indeed $Tx_n \to Tx$ weakly.

Now suppose the contrary, that $\| Tx_n - Tx \| \not\to 0$, then we can find a subsequence $\{ Tx_{n_k}\}_k$ and a constant $C$ such that 
\begin{equation}
\| Tx_{n_k} - Tx \| \geq C \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Since since $x_n \to x$ weakly, then $\{x_{n_k}\}_k$ Is bounded, and being $T$ compact we can find a subsequence of $\{ Tx_{n_k}\}_k$, say $\{ Tx_{n_{k'}}\}_{k'}$, such that 
$$
Tx_{n_{k'}} \to y 
$$
Which gives that $Tx_{n_{k'}} \to y $ weakly. However, since weak limits are unique, by the first paragraph we have that $y = Tx$ and hence that 
$$
Tx_{n_{k'}} \to Tx
$$
A contradiction of (1)!! Therefore indeed
$$
\| Tx_n - Tx \| \to 0
$$